# How can i create an Vista like expansion button with MFC?

Tags: user-interface, mfc, windows-vista

I mean the round expansion button that is used for example in the Task Dialog on Vista.

See this image from the MFC documentation of CTaskDialog.

[image: Image from the MFC documentation of CTaskDialog]

Comment: One tip, did you try to figure out the window class using the Spy++ tool from VisualStudio?

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure your application is Unicode.
2. Ensure you are using VS2005 or higher that can embed resource manifest by themselves, OR do it manually.

Just do this:

- Create an MFC Dialog based application using VS2008 - Use all default settings.

Comment: So what is the button style flag for this or how can i get the icon?